# How can I configure Microsoft Insights to store logs

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to configure Microsoft Insights in an app based in Vue. My idea is to sent specific logs there, with the info that I consider relevant.
I've created the resource in Azure and got its instrumentation key. Looking at the documentation we can load this like this

```
import { ApplicationInsights } from '@microsoft/applicationinsights-web'

const appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({ config: {
  instrumentationKey: 'YOUR_INSTRUMENTATION_KEY_GOES_HERE'
} });
appInsights.loadAppInsights();
appInsights.trackPageView();
```

My question is, how can I send specific logs?
I'm looking for something similar to:

`appInsights.log('Info that I want to log');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [trackTrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#tracktrace):

```js
appInsights.trackTrace({message: 'Info that I want to log'});
```

traces are generally used for diagnostic logging. If you want to capture certain business related events you can use [trackEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#trackevent):

```js
appInsights.trackEvent({
  name: 'some event',
  properties: { // accepts any type
    prop1: 'string',
    prop2: 123.45,
    prop3: { nested: 'objects are okay too' }
  }
});
```

Custom properties can be included in your telemetry through the properties named argument. This can be done with any of the Track APIs like in the example above.

For more background, see [the GitHub repo](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS)

Comment: Works correct, thanks! To isolate the traffic so only traffic from a specific domain will be sent to Microsoft Insights, can I use the Network Isolation configuration or does that only allow to specific IPs?